# How to convert presentation to word processing file (pptx to odt or docx)?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-powerpoint, conversion, libreoffice-writer, libreoffice-impress

I was asked to convert the Presentation to the Writer/Word document.

As I can see it is possible to save the presentation file as `rtf` file, but it means that some formatting is lost.

I've tried to use `pandoc`:

```
pandoc -o myFile.docx myFile.pptx
```

but the output says:

```
pandoc: Cannot decode byte '\xaf': 
Data.Text.Internal.Encoding.Fusion.streamUtf8: Invalid UTF-8 stream
```

Pandoc allows to set [encoding](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#character-encoding), but I can't find information how the PowerPoint file is encoded. How can I do that or is there any better way to convert to this output?

Comment: [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/) doesn't seem to support the conversion at all.

Comment: You mean conversion from PPTX. Is there any other tool to use for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

There is a product called [George for PowerPoint](https://www.greatcirclelearning.com/george/) that might help you. It is not free though, but you can subscribe to it by the month. It will extract all text from the PowerPoint slides, formatted or unformatted, and put it into a Word document. It will also create handouts from the slides in 18 different formats.

Full disclosure ... I am the author.

Answer (score 0):

Pandoc is great if content is in Markdown (.md)

There is a handy open source [PPTX to Markdown converter](https://github.com/ssine/pptx2md)
It's not bad, and includes the images.

Although there may always be some final editing to do in the target output format.

You could then convert from Markdown to Word using Pandoc ...

Here is [article on converting from Markdown to Word (docx)](https://www.mscharhag.com/software-development/pandoc-markdown-to-pdf)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).